# Error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]

Tags: graphics, packages

Please do not mark this as duplicate question. I looked at previous posts and could not solve the problem.
I have this line in my tex script:

```
\includegraphics \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{test.jpg}
```

It produces this error:

```
Error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
```

When I comment the line, I can compile the script successfully. I also included these packages for it to work:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{bmpsize}
```

**EDIT:** My image has reasonable size. It is about 150 KB.

Comment: Why do you have two \includegraphics?

Comment: You've got `\includegraphics` twice in your code line: if that's really the case, you'll need to fix it.